# Reading time using Apache POI HSSFCell getting error

Tags: java, apache-poi

Hi i am trying to read an excel sheet value with the `HSSFCell`. My excel shhet consistes of 4 columns. Date, Name, In_time and Out_time.

in my loop i have given..

```
            HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) itr.next();
            Iterator cell = row.cellIterator();
            List data = new ArrayList();
            while(cell.hasNext())
            {
                HSSFCell value = (HSSFCell) cell.next();

                if (value.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) 
                {
                    if(HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(value))
                    {
                        if(HSSFDateUtil.isADateFormat((int)value.getNumericCellValue(), "dd:mmm:yyyy"))
                        {
                            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                            String date = df.format(value.getDateCellValue());
                            data.add(date);
                        }
                                             }
                        else

                    {
                        data.add(value.getNumericCellValue());
                    }
                }
                else if (value.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
                {
                    data.add(value.getStringCellValue());
                }
                else
                {
                    data.add("");
                }
            }
            sheetData.add(data);
```

the fields date ans name are retriveing correctly.
But when ever i tries to get the time, its giving so date value.. For example in my excel i have the time 4:05:12 AM.. But its taking the value as some date like 1899-12-30..
How can i read a date value from an excel sheet using Apache POI..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be explicitly formatting the cell as a "yyyy-MM-dd" date, via a call to a SimpleDateFormat. So, it's shouldn't be a surprise that you're getting exactly what you asked for, and ending up with a yyyy-MM-dd date string!

Currently, your explicit yyyy-MM-dd code, taken from your question, is the slightly odd:

```
 if(HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(value))
     {
     if(HSSFDateUtil.isADateFormat((int)value.getNumericCellValue(), "dd:mmm:yyyy"))
                    {
                        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                        String date = df.format(value.getDateCellValue());
                        data.add(date);
                    }
```

If you want to format the cell so it looks the same as it does in Excel, then you need to take account of the formatting rules applied to the cell. If you do that, your code would instead look something much simpler like:

```
 DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();

 .....

 if(HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(value)) {
     String date = formatter.formatCell(value);
 }
```

If the cell has a yyyy-MM-dd format applied to it, then you'll still get something like 2012-07-20. If it's a time format instead, then you'll get that.

Comment: BUt how can i handle time? When i tried as u said, i got time as String. But my database has given it as time, not var char

Comment: What do you want it as? Specifically, what Java Object do you want to get it in? POI will give you the cell as a Date, which has a time component, or you can turn it into a string with the above, either one of those ought to be fine for almost everything

Comment: Sorry my friend. You are exactly right. Thank u.. +100 for that ans..
thank u